# Matrix multiplication randomised verification - error probability

Tags: probability-theory, matrix, testing

Let s  say we have an algorithm that takes as input 3 matrix A,B and C

> $$ \text{Input} :A,B,C \in Mat(n\times n)$$
>   $$\text{Question} :\text{is } A\cdot B=C$$

the algorith works as follow ;

$$ \text{if }(A\cdot B)_{ij}=C_{ij} \Rightarrow A\cdot B=C  $$
$$ \text{if }(A\cdot B)_{ij} \neq C_{ij} \Rightarrow A\cdot B \neq C  $$

with random chosen $i$ and $j$  .

I have to find in this case the error probrabilty. Can someone please give me some hints.

This problem looks a bit like  the freivalds algorithm, somehow i think i have to drive a trick with it so solve mine but i am not sure .

Comment: Well, $C$ could be wrong on a single entry, so the error probability could be quite large.

Comment: yeah but how much , i am guessing by 0.5

Comment: Don’t guess, calculate.

Comment: Use the definition of probability. Count the number of elements to choose and the size of the space. Distinguish the cases where the answer is yes and the answer is no and output the smaller probability among both.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the whole algorithm, only one iteration, then the only bound on the probability of error you can get is that it is smaller than $1-1/n^2$.

Hint 1) Notice that the algorithm only can fail when it enters in the first case you describe, why?

Hint 2) What is the worst possible case for A, B and C so you get the worse probability of error?

Answer (score 0):

If I create the matrix C by calculating AB, then change a single entry in C, then you need to calculate x% of all entries to have an x% chance to find the incorrect entry.

If I change an entry in A or B, then you just need to calculate 2n entries ( but the right ones) to find AB != C.

So really your question is unanswerable until you get more information about A, B and C.